# Need a regex which matches all elements like <space>@someText<space>

Tags: javascript, regex

Exceptions:

- beginning of string --> match without first space
- end of string --> match without last space

Examples:

```
const test1 = '@test1 @test2 @test3'
const test2 = '@test1  @test2'
const test3 = '@test1  @test2 @test3 @test4'
```

The closest which I came to is next regex:

```
const closestSolution = /(?:\s|^)@[A-Za-z0-9\-\.\_\#]*(?:\s|$)/g
```

So the results with my closes solution are:

```
const res1 = test1.match(closestSolution)
const res2 = test2.match(closestSolution)
const res3 = test3.match(closestSolution)
console.log(res1) // returns ["@test1 ", " @test3"] when expected ["@test1", "@test2", "@test3"]
console.log(res2) // returns ["@test1 ", " @test2"] when expected ["@test1", "@test2"]
console.log(res3) // returns ["@test1 ", " @test2 ", " @test4"] when expected ["@test1", "@test2", "@test3", "@test4"]
```

Comment: use can use group like this: `(\@\w+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your may avoid of explicit spaces handling and focus on @ and other meaningful data:

```
const new_solution = /@[A-Za-z0-9\-\.\_\#]+/g
```

Comment: test3 and test4 are not expected in the output. They don't start with '@'.

Comment: `const closestSolution = /@[A-Za-z0-9\-\.\_\#]+/g` probably is the right answer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Corrected mistype in the question, so there were '@test3' and '@test4'

Comment: /@[A-Za-z0-9\-\.\_\#]+/g looks like what I was looking for (/@?[A-Za-z0-9\-\.\_\#]+/g is correct for the initial question version). Thanks.